# storing indexpath in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

So I'm trying to store a cell's indexpath when my custom cell is created in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I define a custom cell in class called "custom cell", and I added a property to that class defined as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I set the index path with `customCell.indexPath = indexPath.`

When I `NSLog` it on the very next line it returns null. Could somebody please explain why this is happening?

**Edit**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EditableCell";

EditableCell *editableCell = (EditableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (editableCell == nil) {

    editableCell = [[EditableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

_myTextField = [editableCell textFieldCell];

if (indexPath.section == 0){
    [_myTextField setPlaceholder:@"text"];
    [_myTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    [_myTextField setPlaceholder:@"text"];
    [_myTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
}
else {
    [_myTextField setPlaceholder:@"text"];
    [_myTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
}

_myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
_myTextField.delegate = self;

return editableCell;
```

}

Where I call [self.tableview indexpathforcell:cell]

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext) {

    UITableViewCell* myCell = (UITableViewCell*)textField.superview;
    EditableCell *currentCell = (EditableCell *)myCell;


       NSLog(@"INDEXPATH OF CURRENT CELL: %@",[self.tableView indexPathForCell:currentCell]);   
}     
}
```

Comment: You're not understanding something here - why do you think you need to save the indexPath of the cell in the cell itself?

Comment: are you sure, u created an object `customCell`?

Comment: @AshleyMills, there are cases, where it makes sense to store the indexPath inside a cell. Right now, I am working on a tableView, that will display tabular data. the custom cell gets knowledge about it's index path, so that it can call its own delegate method with it, that will help it configuring the n labels, that it will put on itself.

Comment: is it possible to post the whole implementation of `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`? and the NSLog?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - 13K rating or not, I think you should read the UITableView docs again!

Comment: @AshleyMills, could you explain why?

Comment: @vikingosegundo See my winning answer to this question.

Comment: @AshleyMills, you should maybe read more carefully. I didnt say, that there is the need to save the indexpath in the cell for this task. I said, there are situations, where it can be useful. That's why I didnt wrote it as an aster to the OP, but as comment to you. And I am totally familiar with the apple docs.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I'd stick with Django if I were you.

Comment: @AshleyMills no need to insult me.

Comment: @AshleyMills Can you give any reason, why it should be absolutly forbidden to let the cell know it's current indexPath? You are the self-declared RockStar programmer. should be kind of easy for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the `indexPath` of a given cell using

```
-[UITableView indexPathForCell:]
```

If the cell needs to know it's own `indexPath`:

```
NSIndexPath * myIndexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell:self]
```

But if it does, something's not right!

Looking at your edited post I see the problem. You need:

```
UITableViewCell* myCell = (UITableViewCell*)textField.superview.superview
```

The `textField` is actually a subview of the cell's `contentView`. This always seems a bit wrong to me, so another way to handle this is to make your custom cell the `UITextFieldDelegate`, and then create a delegate protocol for your cell. So within the cell you'd have:

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext) {
        [self.delegate customCell: self textFieldDidReturn: textField];
    }     

    return NO;
}
```

Then in your **cell's** delegate you'll have a reference to the cell and textField

Comment: I tried using indexPathForCell but it returns null...I'll edit my question and post the code for that as well....

Comment: OK, you're going to have to post more code. Can you add your complete  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, and the method where you tried indexPathForCell:

Comment: unbelievable. Well thanks a lot. You've saved more from another hour of useless debugging.